# Is there a shortcut in LyX to exit ERT mode?

Tags: lyx

I know that C-l ENTERS ERT mode,  but my question is-
Is there a shortcut in LyX to EXIT ERT mode ?

Comment: Does <Right> (the right arrow key) do what you want? ERT is a box. When you do ctrl + L, you create a box and enter it. To exit it, you just need to move to the right if you are at the right edge of the box.

Answer (score 4):

The escape key. It works in most insets in LyX e.g. notes and equations.